# Android, intent doesn't work?

Tags: android, button, android-intent, tabs, android-tabhost

This is my code. Its very simple but when I click on the button "button1", nothing happens. What did I do wrong?

```
public class TestTab extends Activity {

    Button button1;
        Intent i;


    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScore);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Click Event", 5000).show();

                //i = new Intent(TestTab.this, AndroidTab.class);
                //startActivity(i);

            }

        });
   }}
```

second--

```
package com.example.picturegame2;

import android.app.TabActivity;


public class AndroidTab extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabzz);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        TabSpec localspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Local");
        localspec.setIndicator("Local", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.friend));
        Intent localIntent = new Intent(this, local.class);
        localspec.setContent(localIntent);

        TabSpec worldwidespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("worldwide");
        worldwidespec.setIndicator("Worldwide", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.worldwide));
        Intent worldwideIntent = new Intent(this, worldwide.class);
        worldwidespec.setContent(worldwideIntent);

        tabHost.addTab(worldwidespec);
        tabHost.addTab(localspec);



    }


}
```

third--

```
package="com.example.picturegame2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".local"/>
    <activity android:name=".AndroidTab"/>
    <activity android:name=".TestTab"/>
    <activity android:name=".tabzz"/>
    <activity android:name=".worldwide"/>
</application>
```

layout--

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Start New Game"
        android:id="@+id/BtnGame"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/LsOpenGames"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp" 

        ></ListView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Profile"
        android:id="@+id/btnProfile"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="375dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Score"
        android:id="@+id/btnScore"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="375dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

New Logcat:
11-29 12:15:39.552: D/gralloc_goldfish(613): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-29 12:15:40.062: I/Choreographer(613): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-29 12:16:08.902: I/Choreographer(613): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: Is there any exception in logcat? And have you added the new activity in manifest file?

Comment: Y are there two Intent i statment ?

Comment: can you please post your AndroidManifest.xml file and logact also

Answer (score 5):

You have to remove the globally declared **Intent** variable like this,

```
 Button button1;
 @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScore);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         Intent i = new Intent(TestTab.this, AndroidTab.class);
         startActivity(i);

            }

        });
    }
```

Or try this,

```
     Button button1;
     Intent i;


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScore);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     i = new Intent(TestTab.this, AndroidTab.class);
     startActivity(i);

        }

    });
}
```

Your `startActivity(i)` could have been referencing the globally declared **Intent** variable which you forgot to initialize and created a **Intent** object locally with the same name "i" as of the globally declared one.

If the above ideas didn't help you, then  as the user  Yajneshwar Mandal has suggested you need to try it. Or put a log inside the ClickListener to see if the control gets into it.

Comment: But i think that this is not the reason.In this case startActivity(i); always get the value from local intent I . If you declare a Intent with same name golbaly , i think that it will not effect to the startActivity(i); . Prblem in Manifest/ new Activity class.

Comment: I have tested his code. (two intent global and local). It is working fine . Please post manifest and the AndroidTab   . then it will be clear.But whatever u say is not the reason i think.

Comment: maybe the AndroidTab class has to be checked to see if it has extended Activity. Isn't it? Bcoz if he hadn't declared it in the manifest then surely it would have crashed. If there is no such class at all then he could got a compile time error.

Comment: He made mistake in Androidmanifest. He did not declare the Activity in the manifest

Comment: but then the application would crash rite?

Comment: </activity>
        <activity android:name="local"/>
        <activity android:name="AndroidTab"/>
        <activity android:name="TestTab"/>
        <activity android:name="tabzz"/>
        <activity android:name="worldwide"/>
    </application>       this is a part of my manifest file

Comment: @user1852886 did you try SahilMahajanMj's solution also?

Comment: yes i have, it did not work? i dont have any errors or something weird in the logcat? when i press the score button nothing happens? also how do i post a new piece of code? like how do i post my whole manifest?

Comment: can u plz post the total manifest. And what is the package name in the manifest. <activity android:name="AndroidTab"/> . if att the activity is in the same package then add "." before AndroidTab . replace ur <activity android:name="AndroidTab"/> with <activity android:name=".AndroidTab"/>

Comment: you will find the edit option below your question. Click on it and edit your same question.

Comment: i get this 
   " Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.
    Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly." when trying to add my androidtab.java file or my manifest?

Comment: and this is the package name of the manifets package="com.example.picturegame2"

Comment: which package does your Activity belong to?

Comment: so Plase add a "."(dot) before AndroidTab like : <activity android:name=".AndroidTab"/> , then  Run ur project and let me know the result

Comment: i've did like you set with the dot before AndroiTab, and there's no diffrence, the button still doesnt do anything when i press it

Comment: which package does your Activity belong to? – Andro Selva...... ans this question

Comment: i put my androidtab.java file on maybe you can figure something out from that, in the meanwhile i'll try to get my manifest on here, but already need to thank you guys for tyring to help me so much, very nice

Comment: post ur activity_main.xml also

Comment: Last thing is that ...please  check  button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScore); . Do you add proper id btnScore for button1.

Comment: i've uploaded my activity_main.xml file @Yajneshwar Mandal

Comment: I can not get the exact problem . need to see ur full code . If u upload it somewhere then i will try to solve it

Answer (score 3):

```
public class TestTab extends Activity {

Button button1;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScore);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(TestTab.this, AndroidTab.class);
    //i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
    startActivity(i);

        }

    });
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be two problems

1. you are declaring your intents twice, first globally and then locally. The system might be referencing the global decleration.
2. Secondly,
   you have used

   ```
   button1.setOnCLickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()

   ...     );
   ```

here you should use,

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Comment: have you tried using **View.onClickListener()** in place of Button.onClickListener()**.? Also what's the problem you are facing. is there any error or something else.?

Comment: yes i've tried that, and no i dont have any errors, the button just doest do anything when i click it

Comment: Cross check that whether its the same button you have mentioned in your classes and xml and that you are clicking on. also try printing some log to check whether the onClick event is working or not.

Comment: i cant figure out how to check the onclick?

Comment: just print some toast in the onCLick event. **Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Click Event", 5000).show();**

Comment: it doesnt do anything? so i assume its has something to do with the onclick?

Comment: yes, button's onCLick is not working. you should use **View.onClickListener()** instead of **Button.onClickLisetener()**. also check that the button ID for both the buttons is same, one you are clicking on and the one you have used in class.

Comment: i've already checked it, its the same button, and i also tried the toast with the View.onClick, still nothing?

Comment: post the updated code, where you have replaced **Button** with **View** and added the toast. Post that in the question by editing the question.

Comment: i have tested your code and its working fine. cant figure out why its not in your case. What's the button name you are clicking on.? **Score**.?

Comment: yh de button text is "Score" and the id is btnScore

Comment: there's nothing else one can do now, i have tested your code and its running extremely well. try cleaning and rebuilding your code.

Comment: still embarassed that a simple problem is not solved. but there's nothing wrong with your code. now what you can do is to create a new project and do add this functionality in it.

Comment: yeah it's really weird, what do you mean with functionality?

Comment: have you by any chance tested the                                     "i = new Intent(TestTab.this, AndroidTab.class);
       startActivity(i);" part?

Comment: yes i have tested this with my own class names and its working for me.

Comment: hmm i think ill completly rebuild it, see if that helps, ill update you when im done :)

Comment: well, the bad news is that it doesnt work, good news is that he does show something in the logcat "11-28 08:30:54.571: I/Choreographer(617): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
" i dont know what this would mean tho?

Comment: can you post the new logcat. edit your question and post it there.

Comment: 11-29 08:29:22.403: D/gralloc_goldfish(639): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-29 08:29:22.773: I/Choreographer(639): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: that's the whole logcat, yesterday it did say some more

Comment: and it seems i cant edit my code, it keeps saying its not properly formated as code

Comment: there might be some problem with your sdk or the avd manager. have you debugged any other application or is it your first application.?

Comment: i have formatted your code properly. now tou can add your extra code and replace the words **second** and **thrird** with your classes name.

Comment: i've tested my code on a phone (samsung galaxy s2) and there when i pres new game the text does show (not on my emulator) but the button score still doesnt do anything

Comment: so its working on your phone.? here in the above code, you have defined the **onClick** event of only one code.

Comment: i also have an java file so when you click the "new game" button you get a popup, thats working fine yes, but the other 2 buttons doesnt work tho

Comment: damn, now i get another error on the other onclicklistener, now w/ fatal error so my app wont even open anymore

Comment: Does your all other classes extends Activity.?

Comment: i've put underneath the code, its failing because of another onclick

Comment: which is your line number 27 in MainActivity class.